# how to upload a zip file using curl to a https site using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

how to upload a zip file using curl to a https site using cakephp?
I want to upload a zip file to a url using cakephp.

```
    $data1 = array('file' => "@/".  realpath($file)."type=application/zip", 
                    'Content-Type'=>'application/zip'
                    );


        $response = $this->_socket->post($this->url, $data1 , array('redirect' => true));
```

Comment: please be more precise on what you want to achieve and also include what you have tried/done so far. we're not here to do the job for you..

Comment: I have added code please check

Comment: It is giving me error ErrorCode: assessment-content-error (NOT_XML_OR_ZIP)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you.

```
$data1 = array('file' => "@/".  realpath($file)."type=application/zip", 
                    'Content-Type'=>'application/zip',
                    'sslVerifyPeer' => false /* try using both values true or false */
                    );


    $response = $this->_socket->post($this->url, $data1 , array('redirect' => true));
```